# Bash script hand over input instead of exit

Tags: bash, scripting, ftp, terminal, netcat

Is there a way to have a bash script hand over execution to the user in its current state upon exiting?  For example, I would a script that logs into an FTP server with "nc ip-address 21", runs a couple of commands, and then hands over an already initiaed FTP shell to the user.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is auto login, use ncftp... it supports auto login and scripting for ftp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cat command at the end of a piped input, but then make sure to start bash interactive (-i option) in order to be shown the prompt:

Example with an echo and a list command, then accepting user input

```c
( echo '
echo "these commands are piped before user input begins"
ls -lrt /directory/you/want/to/show/the/contents/of/before/user/input/begins/
' ; cat) | bash -i
```

btw, I use it to define functions in bash.

Possibly, you may have to adjust the ftp program to accept ordinary standard input, but if that is the case, it would probably accept your commands anyway.